# What do you disable, uninstall, remove from your OLTP SQL Server to keep it as clean as possible?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for answers on all the services you disable, anything that you disable, uninstall, etc.  The goal of this topic/question is have a running checklist of things that do **NOT** need to be on a SQL Server for an OLTP-type system.

I've not been able to find a definitive list on this topic, just various things here and there.

I wanted this list for my own edification as well as something the community could refer to as needed.

My thought is to update the list as folks make suggestions in the original post.

I know that some of the topics that'll come up can be considered subjective, but either way, I'd like you to explain your reasoning for why you make the suggested modification or disablement.  Not all of these are blatantly obvious.

Comment: Don't install any features you aren't going to use.  Don't use the server for anything except running those SQL Server features you need.

Comment: Current versions of Windows and SQL Server already have significantly reduced default surface area. The next major surface area reduction comes from using Windows Server Core but make sure you know what you're getting into. They're really not kidding when they said minimalistic. Admins that only know how to use the GUI tools locally will have an unpleasant surprise. As for SQL Server, it only installs what you explicitly selected so create your own minimalist config file for SQL Server installs to include only the components you need.